# NullPointerException app loading

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

When my app loads the following error comes up on some devices.  It refers to none of my source files at all!  How do I go about fixing this one?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:494)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6739)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1872)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here: [Marking Current Location on Map, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091127/marking-current-location-on-map-android) and here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2035, you may need to call `overlays.populate();` method in your code.

Comment: Thanks but I already have that in my Overlay constructor at the end of it!

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/43615742f462bbf1/8918ddfc92808c42?pli=1